# UI List not updating jetpack compose with mutableList but data updates

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata

Why is my list not updating? I spent the whole day yesterday, debugging this and researching but I couldn't find anything to help me.
I have a companion object in my fragment, which is initially an empty mutableList:

```kotlin
class MainTillLayoutFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        var mBasket = mutableListOf<Product?>()
    }
...
}
```

I have a method called addToBasket. which gets a "Product" item as a parameter and it adds it to the mBasket:

```kotlin
    private fun addToBasket(product: Product) {
        mBasket.add(product)
        println("PRODUCTS ADDED NEW BASKET IS $mBasket")
    }
```

And then I have a composable function that uses mBasket in the items() function to loop through each of the products and display a Text in each row of the lazyColumn:

```kotlin
 LazyColumn(
     modifier = Modifier
         .background(color = Color.Red)
         .fillMaxSize(),
     content = {
          items(mBasket) {
                if (it != null) {
                     Text(text = it.name)
                      }
                }
         }
   )
```

The data DOES get updated HOWEVER the UI does NOT, anything wrong with the code above that I should try guys?

Thanks in advance everyone :)

Comment: You need to use Compose's own version of state e.g. `mutableStateOf`....updating that then will trigger recomposition.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly yeah i just found the answer actually! I had to use mutableStateListOf which I think is what you meant, thank you very much for your help mate!

Comment: You can also use `mutableStateOf` here and often that's more appropriate if the data you're interested in is already a list e.g. you might have a view model that exposes that (as perhaps flow) ....in that case you'd also perhaps use something like `collectAsState` to convert to state variable

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I FOUND THE FIX
If anybody ever needs it, instead of using mutableListOf<>(), try using mutableStateListOf<>(), which should keep track of the STATE and recompose the view automatically for you!!

In my case instead of

```kotlin
    var mBasket = mutableListOf<Product?>()
```

I should have done

```kotlin
    var mBasket = mutableStateListOf<Product?>()
```